# AngularJs dynamic model generation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make my ng-model dynamic, when i use only one level object `ng-model="data[question.option_group_id]"` it works fine. However when try to use 2 level object structure `ng-model="data[page.id][question.option_group_id]"` it gives me error: *TypeError: Cannot set property '10' of undefined.*

```
<div class="radio" ng-repeat="option in question.option_group.option_choices">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="data[page.id][question.option_group_id]" value="{{ option.id }}" name="{{ question.option_group_id }}">
        {{ option.name }}
    </label>
</div>
```

Any ideas how can this be solved ?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle/plunker to see how it is defined in your scope please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `data[page.id][question.option_group_id]`. This will throw the error you are seeing unless you define `data[page.id]` first. You can navigate to `data[page.id][question.option_group_id]` only if `data[page.id]` has been defined.

Comment: I see, is there a way to define `data[page.id]` it in the view ?

Comment: You cannot define data[page.id] in the view. You have to do it in the controller.

Comment: Yes that's what I did eventually. Thanks for help.

Comment: I think you can try <div class="radio" ng-repeat="option in question.option_group.option_choices" ng-init='data[page.id]={}'>